# SCSS files not compiling to CSS in react using Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, sass

Following is my folder structure & Files for `React` project which is working fine but I am unable to add `CSS` through `SCSS` via `Webpack` using `extract-text-webpack-plugin`. Let me know what I am doing wrong with the configuration.

**Folder Structure -**

[image: Folder Structure]

**Webpack.config.js File -**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './app/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPluginConfig = new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css',{
    allChunks: true
});

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig, ExtractTextPluginConfig]
};
```

**Package.json -**

```
{
  "name": "reactyarn",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  }
}
```

**FYI -**

I am not getting any JS error in console, so I believe its only the configuration which is not working.

[image: Console]

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be missing one of the loaders (`sass-loader`) and setting them up in your modules incorrectly.

Try the example below:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './app/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] // <-- this is new
        ]
    },
    sassLoader: {
      includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'relative/path/to/scss')]
    }, // <--- this is new
    plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig, ExtractTextPluginConfig]
};
```

By using `ExtractPlugin.extract` you're referencing the means to do this in Webpack 2 (using `rules` and `use`) but your Webpack config file appears to be geared toward Webpack 1.

Comment: I made the changes as per your comment but now I am facing error in cmd prompt ..File - https://pastebin.com/5gW7eRXU Error - http://i.imgur.com/4jTZITW.png

Comment: Check documentation here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/tree/archive/webpack-1 - Also, ensure you've installed `node-sass` via `npm i -D node-sass`